# Windows 11 upgrade aborts and roll back all changes made, how/where can I find out why?

Tags: windows-11

I started the Windows 11 upgrade today and it downloaded, installed, then rebooted to that black update screen and started ticking.

Turning away to check my food for one second, then turning back and there is a "rolling back changes" screen ticking, before Windows reboots back to Windows 10.

I've scoured the event log to see if I can figure out why but I'm unable to find a concrete error message in there that appears to be related. Is there a log file or similar written during the upgrade, one that would tell me what the reason was? If so, where would I find this log file? My google-fu seems to fail me.

Comment: There will be upgrade logs>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/log-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 11 upgrade will only roll back if the machine is deemed to be incompatible with Windows 11 at the time it tried to upgrade.

1. Make sure no Dual Boot (at least for the time being).
2. Make sure the disk is GPT and you are using UEFI.
3. Make sure Secure Boot is enabled.
4. Make sure the machine is equipped with Hardware TPM version 2.
5. If Windows 10 Home, make sure you are using a Microsoft Account.

Make sure of the above settings and try again.

You may have some software installed that is not Windows 11 compliant. Go through your various software upgrades to check. Make sure IE is not trying to be used. Upgrade to Chromium Edge will fix that. Make sure Office and Adobe are all up to date.

Comment: It was secure boot that was missing. Thanks. Strange that the in-Windows upgrade assistant didn't detect this.

Comment: Yes. Normally the upgrade process will detect Secure Boot.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue though my pc was supported. I did uninstall Edge from my system and win 11 had upgrades to edge so my uninstall broke the chain and it reverted. I reinstalled Edge and it fixed.